# Unable to install Pillow on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, python, python-2.7, pip, django

I m trying to install pillow via the command :

```
pip install pillow
```

on my Ubuntu machine but I repeatedly get this error:

```
command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix this error and use pillow for my Django project ?

(I don't know it matters or not but I m using Python2.7)

UPADTE:

[image: SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR WINDOW]

Comment: Wily is EOL very very soon. I recommend you upgrade to Xenial when you can. Xenial is LTS and supported til April 2021.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. It is likely you are missing a dependency for compiling software and that list is long. There should be information about what it is in a log or on-screen.

Comment: If i Upgrade to Xenial then will i loose all my installed software ?

Comment: No, you will just upgrade the binaries that make up your OS. Be sure your backups are sufficient before you start (just i case)

Comment: @Rinzwind There you go

Comment: use copy/paste not an image please ;-) the errors start outside of the images... I would assume there to be a "first" error somewhere that would have the more important parts :)

Comment: Shouldn't you have used `sudo pip install pillow` for that?